# palindromeRearranging

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, инспекция-кода

Подскажите пожалуйста, я тут решал задачку на CodeSignal:"palindromeRearranging" и немного встрял.
Суть такая: на вход приходит строка рандомная и нужно понять: будет ли строка палиндромом, если мы перетасуем элементы в ней.

Первая мысль, что пришла в голову: разделить строку на две части, дальше их отсортировать и проверять равные ли они, но потом понял, что идея не очень-то и работает.

И вот вспомнил про великий компонент collections.Counter, через который написал следующий код:

```
import collections
def palindromeRearranging(inputString):
    rearrange = False
    c = collections.Counter()
    b = []
    for i in inputString: 
        c[i] += 1 # считаю каждую букву
   
    freq_list = c.values()
    minimum = min(freq_list) # количество реже всего встречающихся букв
    maximum = max(freq_list) # количество чаще всего встречающихся букв
    
    if maximum % 2 == 0 or maximum == 1: # палиндром будет тогда, когда число самых встречающихся букв будет четное или если оно равно 1
        for i in c:
            if (c[i] == minimum): # если число определенных букв в строке повторяется минимальное количество раз, то заносим букву в массив b
                b.append(i)
    
    if len(b) > minimum or len(b) == 0: # если в массиве больше букв, чем минимальное число или если в массиве вообще нет букв, то возвращаем False
        return rearrange
    else: return True
```

В целом мне понравилась моя идея и хотел держаться ее, хоть это и два цикла (время страдает) плюс из-за массива b сложность по памяти возрастает. Но ночью ничего лучше не смог придумать.

Было бы круто, если бы кто-то помог понять, в чем проблема данного кода.

ЗАРАНЕЕ БЛАГОДАРЮ!

UPD: с кодом в одну строку мы почти спелись, тогда добавляется еще вопрос: как прийти к такому навыку однострочья и полезно ли это? особенно в читабельности

```
from collections import Counter
def palindromeRearranging(s):
    print (Counter(s).values())
    return sum(i % 2 == 1 for i in Counter(s).values()) <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Первый код непонятный и избыточный. Зачем вы вручную инкрементируете частоту элементов в `Counter`, когда он сам это должен делать? Ну и идея какая-то странная. Не важно, частые буквы или редкие, не должно быть **никаких** букв в строке, встречающихся нечётное число раз, кроме может быть одной максимум. Редкие буквы или частые - разницы никакой нет.

Второй код почти идеальный, только можно не проверять равенство, `i % 2 == 1` и `i % 2` дают одинаковое значение, поэтому можно суммировать просто `i % 2`.

И если тут речь о фразах-палиндромах, а не одиночных словах, например, если в терминах данной задачи фраза "А роза упала на лапу Азора" является палиндромом, то нужно ещё:

- убирать/не считать пробелы - в фразах-палиндромах они могут расставляться произвольно, имеющееся число пробелов соблюдать не нужно
- приводить все буквы к одному регистру - потому что опять же регистр можно менять при перетасовывании букв